# OS X Terminal hangs installing vNext KVM after running "source kvm.sh"

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to install vNext on my Macbook but when I run `source kvm.sh` the terminal just hangs.

---

**My setup:**

- OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks)
- Mono 3.10.0

---

**My problem:**
I followed the instructions for installing vNext on OS X from the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/aspnet/Home

*Essentially:*

- brew tap aspnet/k
- brew install kvm
- source kvm.sh

Everything seems to go fine until the step where I run `source kvm.sh`, which hangs the terminal with a message "*[Process completed]*".

Adding `source kvm.sh` to ~/.zshrc file starts the terminal and immediately hangs it once that runs.

---

**What I've tried:**
I uninstalled kvm (`brew uninstall kvm`) and aspnet/k (`brew untap aspnet/k`) and deleted the directory `~/.kre`, then tried reinstalling it all again.

No luck.

---

**Any ideas?**  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to https://github.com/aspnet/kvm/issues/83 , you can replace the `kvm.sh` file with the version from dev branch, which can be found under https://github.com/aspnet/kvm/blob/dev/src/kvm.sh , and zsh should be happy with it afterwards.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The kvm currently not working in ZSH, Running it under /bin/bash should work quite well.

Also, make sure you remove anything to do with kvm from your .zshrc file and you should be good to go again.