# How to add nuget restore to ZSH on a Mac?

Tags: asp.net, vim, gruntjs, zsh, kvm

How can I add NuGet to Zsh so I can run `nuget restore` from the command line? I am trying to get [ASP.NET](http://github.com/aspnet/home) on my Mac running Yosemite.

The SO question [OS X Terminal hangs installing vNext KVM after running "source kvm.sh"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926553/os-x-terminal-hangs-installing-vnext-kvm-after-running-source-kvm-sh) is the closest I found to my problem. However, KVM is installed and seems to be working okay. The most recent version of KVM gels with ZSH and is properly sourced.

I used [Omnisharp for Vim](http://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim) via pathogen.  In order to scaffold the project, I am attempting to use [Grunt-Init-CSharpsolution](https://github.com/nosami/grunt-init-csharpsolution).

Everything in Grunt-Init-CSharpsolution worked up until the last line, where I need to get the NuGet packages. Response: `zsh: command not found: nuget`. I tried `mono --runtime=v4.0 NuGet.exe` as well as `mono NuGet.exe`.

The mono version I have is 3.10.0. Vim is using spf-13 if that is of value. XBuild on the server is successful.

I am new to the .Net world, so I am not sure what steps I have missed along the way.

**Update**

Running `kvm list` from the command line returns:

```
Active Version              Runtime Location              Alias
------ -------              ------- --------              -------
  *    1.0.0-beta2          Mono    ~/.kre/packages       default
       nuget                Mono    ~/.kre/packages
```

So NuGet is in KVM, just not active. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please include text like your  `kvm list` output as text blocks, not links to offsite images. Offsite links in general are prone to change, and when an image is text anyway there's no overriding reason not to just paste the text in. Also prefer Markdown to HTML (e.g. hrefs) where possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help with Markdown.